# What are the pros and cons of writing class methods in grails domain classes?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

What are the pros and cons of writing class methods in grails domain classes? I am asking, because I often do not see any grails projects with methods inside the domain classes, only data members. Is there a disadvantage to doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a domain class (not just in grails, but in object oriented programming in general), this is known as an [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Martin Fowler proposes that domain logic gets put into the domain class to create a rich domain model. By doing this, domain classes become smarter and know how to perform operations, rather than having another service class that has to operate on the domain class. The pros of having a rich domain model is that the class encapsulates more of its own behavior, and it is more self contained. On the flip side, it does make the domain class more complex. Though I think the domain class should be more than just a business object.

In grails, I tend to try to use a combination of a rich domain model and using services. It's difficult to make a blanket statement as to when a method should be in a domain class and when it should be in a service. As a general rule though, if an operation is complex and requires multiple collaborators, I'll tend to put it in a service class. If the method seems like it should be behavior on the domain class, I'll put it there.

To give a more concrete example, let's take a `Person` class.

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  String lastName
  List<Person> friends
}
```

In our application a person can speak. Now I can have a `TalkService` that knows how a person talks. But in this case, I think that `talk` is a core behavior of the person, so I would add a `talk` method to `Person`.

Let's say I also have functionality where I want to find all of the friends of friends of people (2nd degree friends). To me, this is not core behavior of a `Person`, so I woul delegate this out to a service.

To recap, in general I would add methods to the domain class when it is core behavior of the object (e.g. is it a domain method), otherwise, I would put it in a service.

Answer (score 1):

In a Java project, you must have POJO classes that represents the model.
For example: Person, Invoice, Book, ...

Then there is the service layer, which contains interfaces for users to do some database queries, it takes in parameters your Model, and also return Model, and there is the controller layer which is responsible for redirection and inject your services.

In grails, this is very easy using injection of services into your controller

Now, when do we need to use methods inside the domain classes ? it's when only the model which responsible for what do we need to do, for example, how old is a Person X (it's from the date of birth), how many items exist in a Invoice (from the List), the think is we use that only when we manipulate the data of the current object.

For save method for example, you cannot add it in your model

PersonController :

```
def personService

def save() {
...
Person person = ...
personService.save(person);
...
}
```

This is more evolutive